# I am referencing one field from one collection to another. But whenever there are duplicate, the returned array is distinct

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
router.get('/orderSelect', (req, res, next) =>{
    orderSchema.aggregate([   
        { $lookup:
            {
                from: 'productschemas',
                localField: 'orderItem.productId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'product'
            }
        }
    ], (err, orderSchema) =>{
        if(err) res.json(err);
        else res.json(orderSchema);
    });
});
```

productschemas:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5ba26ff33318b51e20a80fb3",
    "productExist": true,
    "productName": "Oppo",
    "supplierId": "5b9f1e2f5929760568283f95",
    "brandId": "5b9d19e8316e8d2660f26394",
    "categoryId": "5b9d20de9c21fd1b78410d52",
    "productPrice": 4300,
    "productQuantity": 320,
    "productMax": 10,
    "productMin": 4,
    "productTimeStamp": "2018-09-19T15:49:07.177Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

orderSchema

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5ba79a638cef34091c143def",
    "orderItem": [
      {
        "_id": "5ba7a37b4c40dc24d8f4f403",
        "productId": "5ba26ff33318b51e20a80fb3",
        "productPrice": 4300,
        "productQuantity": 2,
        "productTotal": 8600
      },
      {
        "_id": "5ba7a37b4c40dc24d8f4f402",
        "productId": "5ba34f0c133e492a04731c49",
        "productPrice": 2000,
        "productQuantity": 1,
        "productTotal": 2000
      },
      {
        "_id": "5ba7a37b4c40dc24d8f4f401",
        "productId": "5ba26ff33318b51e20a80fb3",
        "productPrice": 4300,
        "productQuantity": 1,
        "productTotal": 4300
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to reference from ordershemas collection the 'orderItem.productId' to collection productschema. i am just saving the object id, and i want to display on the screen the product name not just the id. but whenever there are duplicates, the returned 'product' array is not repeating,

Comment: Could you post sample collections

Comment: productschemas: 
{"_id":"5ba26ff33318b51e20a80fb3","productExist":true,"productName":"Oppo","supplierId":"5b9f1e2f5929760568283f95","brandId":"5b9d19e8316e8d2660f26394","categoryId":"5b9d20de9c21fd1b78410d52","productPrice":4300,"productQuantity":320,"productMax":10,"productMin":4,"productTimeStamp":"2018-09-19T15:49:07.177Z","__v":0}

Comment: orderschemas: 
{"_id":"5ba79a638cef34091c143def", "orderItem":[{"_id":"5ba7a37b4c40dc24d8f4f403","productId":"5ba26ff33318b51e20a80fb3","productPrice":4300,"productQuantity":2,"productTotal":8600},{"_id":"5ba7a37b4c40dc24d8f4f402","productId":"5ba34f0c133e492a04731c49","productPrice":2000,"productQuantity":1,"productTotal":2000},{"_id":"5ba7a37b4c40dc24d8f4f401","productId":"5ba26ff33318b51e20a80fb3","productPrice":4300,"productQuantity":1,"productTotal":4300}]

Comment: for example, i have 2 objects inside orderItem, whenever they have the same objectId, the returned array 'product' is just one in size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `orderItem` array

```
orderSchema.aggregate([   
  { "$unwind": "$orderItem" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": 'productschemas',
    "localField": 'orderItem.productId',
    "foreignField": '_id',
    "as": 'product'
  }},
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$product", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "product": { "$push": "$product" },
    "orderItem": { "$push": "$orderItem" },
    "orderClientName": { "$first": "$orderClientName" },
    "orderContact": { "$first": "$orderContact" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: how can i return all the data from the orderschemas? it returns only the id, product and orderItem

Comment: use `$first` for other fields. I have updated the answer

Comment: it return empty other fields

Comment: what are that fields?

Comment: {"_id":"5ba79a638cef34091c143def","orderClientName":"Shekinah","orderContact":"09173342173","orderItem":[{"_id":"5ba7a37b4c40dc24d8f4f403","productId":"5ba26ff33318b51e20a80fb3","productPrice":4300,"productQuantity":2,"productTotal":8600},{"_id":"5ba7a37b4c40dc24d8f4f402","productId":"5ba34f0c133e492a04731c49","productPrice":2000,"productQuantity":1,"productTotal":2000},{"_id":"5ba7a37b4c40dc24d8f4f401","productId":"5ba26ff33318b51e20a80fb3","productPrice":4300,"productQuantity":1,"productTotal":4300}],"orderTotal":12323,"orderTimeStamp":"2018-09-23T13:51:31.467Z","__v":0}